# Where to add sendmail path in modular muttconf

Tags: smtp, mutt

I use folder hooks in mutt to be able to use it for multiple imap accounts.

I can access the different imap mailboxes without problem via key-bindings and can also switch between them.

I followed this little tutorial to achieve it.

[multiple accounts in mutt using folder-hooks and seperate files](http://evanhanson.com/misc/multiple-accounts-in-mutt)
I just cant figure out in which file the

```
set sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

has to go in this case to be able to send mail to a remote smtp server.

`.mutt` is in `~/` and looks like this:
(f is for file, d for directory)

```
(f)./account.muttrc
(d)./accounts
(d)./cache
(f)./certificates
(f)./muttrc
(f)./sources.muttrc
```

`./sources.muttrc:` speciefies multiple imap hosts, keybindings for switching between them, mutt-commands to execute for switching.

`./accounts/accountx.muttrc:` specifies `from:` address, `imap & smtp` credentials, some account-folder variables.

`./account.muttrc:` sourced everytime i switch the accounts

`./muttrc:` main configuration file looks like this:

```
# .mutt/muttrc
source ~/.mutt/sources.muttrc
folder-hook . source ~/.mutt/account.muttrc
```